# FPDF no puedo hacer reporte si llamo desde otra pagina

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Diseñe un pdf con `fpdf` y al llamarlo directo desde mi **localhost** funciono.
pero cuando lo trasforme en una clase y lo llame desde otra sección de mi sitio pero cuando declaro el `Output()` me da un error el que no entiendo a que se debe.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already
>   been output, can't send PDF file in
>   C:\xxx\docs\hacerpdf\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xxx\docs\hacerpdf\fpdf\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has
>   a...') #1 C:\xxx\docs\hacerpdf\fpdf\fpdf.php(1012):
>   FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xxx\docs\hacerpdf\conducta-save.php(33):
>   FPDF->Output('D') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xxx\docs\hacerpdf\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271

Esta es la pagina que se ejecuta que debería descargar el pdf:

```html
<?php
    include_once('./mypdf1.php');
    $pdf1 = new superPDF();
    $pdf1->hacer();
    $pdf1->Output('D');
?>


esta es la clase donde formateo el pdf:
```

```html
<?php
    require('./fpdf/fpdf.php'); 

    class superPDF extends FPDF
    {  
     function hacer()
     {
         $pdf=new FPDF();
         $pdf->AddPage();
         $pdf->ln(10);
         $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
         $pdf->Cell(0,10,'OBSERVACION DE CONDUCTA','B',1,'C');
         $pdf->ln(3);
         $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
         $pdf->Cell(60,7,'Realizado por:',0,0,'L');
         $pdf->Cell(0,7,'Nombre del trabajador',0,1,'L');
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo tienes que hacer 2 cosas:

- `superPDF` es una clase extendida de `FPDF`, por tanto no es necesario instanciar `FPDF`, puedes utilizar sus métodos con un simple `$this`

> ```
> <?php
> require('./fpdf/fpdf.php');
>
> class superPDF extends FPDF
> {     
>   function hacer()
>     {
>       //$pdf=new FPDF();
>       $this->AddPage('P');
>       $this->ln(10);
>       $this->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
>       $this->Cell(0,10,'OBSERVACION DE CONDUCTA','B',1,'C');
>       $this->ln(3);
>       $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
>       $this->Cell(60,7,'Realizado por:',0,0,'L');
>       $this->Cell(0,7,'Nombre del trabajador',0,1,'L');
>     }
> }
> ```

- Utiliza el método `Output()` sin parámetros, quita esa 'D' y ya veremos cómo hacer que se descargue. De momento hagamos que funcione.

> ```
> <?php 
> include_once('./mypdf1.php');
> $pdf1 = new superPDF();
> $pdf1->hacer();
> $pdf1->Output();
> ```

Comment: Funciono perfecto, y también descubrí otro error o cosa que afectaba, era en donde formateaba el pdf tenia otras lineas de codigo que imprimían con un echo en pantalla otras cosas, eso afectaba y no dejaba ejecutar el Output();

Comment: Pero ahora tengo otra duda, con FPDF puedo tomar una imagen directo desde un Input type="file" y pegarlo en el pdf que genero, no necesito guardar la imagen solo que se genere el pdf.

Comment: Sí, claro... el fichero subido se queda en un archivo temporal que puedes insertar en el PDF. Monta un ejemplo mínimo y envía una nueva pregunta, será un placer ayudarte con ello... :)

Comment: acabo de subbir otro ejemplo y no logro comprender como almacenar el dato de la imagen temporal.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/256411/fpdf-imagen-directo-desde-input