# FPDF imagen directo desde input

Tags: php, archivo, fpdf, fileupload

```
<?php
  require('./fpdf/fpdf.php');   

  $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Image('./img/espex.png',10,10,40);
    $pdf->ln(10);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'OBSERVACION DE CONDUCTA','B',1,'C');
    $pdf->ln(3);
    $pdf->Cell(0,7,'RELATO DE LA SITUACION DETECTADA, INCLUYE LA CORRECCION','B',1,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(0,7,'EVIDENCIA FOTOGRAFICA DE LOS EVENTOS DESCRITOS','B',1,'L');
    $pdf->ln(3);

    $imagenurl =$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];

    $pdf->Cell(95,80, $pdf->Image($imagenurl, $pdf->GetX()+2, $pdf->GetY()+2, 90) ,1,"C");
    $pdf->ln(83);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',11);
    $pdf->Output('D'); 
?>
```

Estoy utilizando la librería FPDF 
Pero tengo una duda solo necesito tomar una foto cargarla en un  type="file" y al apretar submit en el formulario que la imagen se agregue directamente al pdf que genero, pero no necesito guardar nada, solo que quede en el pdf.

No se como hacer esto, tomarlo de algún dato temporal que se guarde o algo así... 
al hacerlo con el código que muestro a continuación me da un error
el erro señala que no se puede de esa forma porque el archivo que carga no es una imagen es un archivo de extencion .tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'])){
    require('./fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    //$pdf->Image('./img/espex.png',10,10,40);
    $pdf->ln(10);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,'OBSERVACION DE CONDUCTA','B',1,'C');
    $pdf->ln(3);
    $pdf->Cell(0,7,'RELATO DE LA SITUACION DETECTADA, INCLUYE LA CORRECCION','B',1,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(0,7,'EVIDENCIA FOTOGRAFICA DE LOS EVENTOS DESCRITOS','B',1,'L');
    $pdf->ln(3);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][0], 'img.jpg');
    $pdf->Cell(95,80, $pdf->Image('img.jpg', $pdf->GetX()+2, $pdf->GetY()+2, 90) ,1,"C");
    unlink('img.jpg');

    $pdf->ln(83);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',11);
    $pdf->Output(); 
}
else{
    echo '
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="img[]" />
            <button>Enviar</button>
        </form>
    ';
}
?>
```

Simplemente muevo el fichero temporal al directorio de trabajo y después lo elimino:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][0], 'img.jpg');
$pdf->Cell(95,80, $pdf->Image('img.jpg', $pdf->GetX()+2, $pdf->GetY()+2, 90) ,1,"C");
unlink('img.jpg');
```

Comment: Funciono de mil maravillas, era lo que andaba buscando .....gracias de verdad @David

Comment: funciono perfecto pero ahora hay algo que no se hacer, estoy haciendo el deploy en heroku.com me el usuario tiene que llenar un formulario y subir una foto y con esa info solo le descarga un pdf que incluye la foto, pero quiero hacer un resize de la foto que la hago con la librería https://dzone.com/articles/resize-image-class-php no se como tomar directo la imagen con el nuevo tamaño y ponerla en el pdf. se podra hacer, no se como mover esta nueva imagen al directorio de trabajo, como lo hacías con move_uploaded_file

Comment: Pues, ya sabes, nueva pregunta y a por ello... :) Puedes usar instrucciones del sistema operativo como copy o move. Recuerda que ya tienes el fichero en tu disco, puedes hacer lo que quieras con él antes de borrarlo...

Comment: nueva pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259558/resize-imagen-y-guardar-directo-en-un-pdf