# Resize imagen, y guardar directo en un PDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Desde mi index.php envió por un form un input type="file" via POST, este POST es recibido por el archivo hacerpdf.php donde los datos del form son pasados directamente a un pdf.
mi problema es con la imagen en hacerpdf.php antes de poner la imagen en el pdf necesito cambiar su tamaño y ponerla directamente en el pdf, esto lo estoy haciendo con la clase Resize Image Class https://dzone.com/articles/resize-image-class-php.
Pasarla directo al PDF me funciona, pero no se como tratarla imagen directo sin guardarla en ninguna parte y ponerla directamente en el pdf.
Aqui va el código que tengo ahora que pasa la imagen directo también tengo el resize pero solo hasta aqui llego. 
esta es hacerpdf.php

```html
<?php 
include('./tamano.php');
require('./fpdf/fpdf.php'); 

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$fecha = date('dmYGis');

$imagenresize= new ResizeImage($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][0]);
$imagenresize->resizeTo(600,600,'exact');
//$imagenresize->saveImage('lafoto.jpg');

 $pdf=new FPDF();
 $pdf->AddPage();
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
 $pdf->Cell(0,10,'OBSERVACION DE CONDUCTA','B',1,'C');
 $pdf->ln(3);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
 $pdf->Cell(60,7,'Realizado por:',0,0,'L');
 $pdf->Cell(0,7,$_POST['quien'],0,1,'L');
 $pdf->Cell(0,7,'EVIDENCIA FOTOGRAFICA DE LOS EVENTOS DESCRITOS','B',1,'L');
 $pdf->ln(3);
  
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][0], 'img.jpg');
  
 $pdf->Cell(95,100, $pdf->Image('img.jpg', $pdf->GetX()+2, $pdf->GetY()+2, 90) ,1,"C");
 unlink('img.jpg');
  
 $pdf->ln(103);
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',11);
 $pdf->MultiCell(190,8,'Mediante la firma del presente informe se deja constancia de quien firma a continuacion toma conocimiento de todas las situaciones detectadas y se compromete a dar cumplimineto a lo que se le instruya',1);
 $pdf->Output('D','informe_ObsConducta-'.$fecha.'.pdf'); //'D' to dowload.

 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer el resize del fichero guardado en el disco en vez del fichero temporal que te envía el formuarlio? Es decir, hacer el `resize` justo después del `move_uploaded()`

Comment: @David,  localmente me funciona bien en mi localhost, pero al subir a heroku no corre me da un error HTTP 500, cual sera el problema